# Qt Drawing transition arrow

Tags: c++, qt

I need help i need to add arrow shaped polygon rotated 45 degree. I need help with transforming this arrow i drew polygon like i need but cant figure out how to rotate it.

```
QBrush greenBrush (Qt::green);

    QPolygonF poly;
    poly << QPoint(0,45);
    poly << QPoint(60,45);
    poly << QPoint(60,35);
    poly << QPoint(100,50);
    poly << QPoint(60,65);
    poly << QPoint(60,55);
    poly << QPoint(0,55);
    poly << QPoint(0,45);

    poly . translate(130,130);
    scene -> addPolygon(poly,blackPen,greenBrush);
```

Expected Output:

[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Unfortunately "please help" [is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/). Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't post a [MCVE]. -- However, I guess `scene` is of type `QGraphicsScene`. In this case, `scene->addPolygon()` returns a `QGraphicsPolygonItem*`. `QGraphicsPolygonItem` is derived from [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html). Now, have a look at the doc. of the latter - there are many transformation functions available, incl. [QGraphicsItem::setRotation()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation).

Answer (score 1):

One possible (if probably simple & inefficient) way would be to use [QTransform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html) to map the points in your vector to the desired rotated positions:

```
QTransform transform;
transform.rotate(desiredAngle);
QList<QPoint> poly;
poly << QPoint(0,45);
poly << QPoint(60,45);
poly << QPoint(60,35);
poly << QPoint(100,50);
poly << QPoint(60,65);
poly << QPoint(60,55);
poly << QPoint(0,55);
poly << QPoint(0,45);
for(int i = 0; i < poly->size(); i++)
    poly->replace(i, transform.map(poly->at(i)));

QPolygon polygon(poly);
```